# Excel - how to add cells with numbers and letters

Tags: worksheet-function

```
ABC123
ABC145
ABC-5898
```

How can I add the numbers in the cell in the column and ignore the letters and characters?

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter the array formula:

```
=--MID(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01"&A1,SMALL((ROW($1:$300)-1)*ISNUMBER(-MID("01"&A1,ROW($1:$300),1)),ROW($1:$300))+1,1),10^(300-ROW($1:$300))),2,300)
```

and copy downwards, then in another cell enter:

```
 =SUM(B1:B3)
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.